# why do I always get an error message with react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

every time I run npm start it gives me an error message:

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    Route,
    NavLink,
    HashRouter
  } from "react-router-dom";
  import Home from "./containers/Home";
  import About from "./containers/About";
  import Resume from "./containers/Resume";
 
class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <HashRouter>
        <div>
          <h1>Simple SPA</h1>
          <ul className="header">
            <li><NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
            <li><NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink></li>
            <li><NavLink to="/resume">Resume</NavLink></li>
          </ul>
          <div className="content">
            <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
            <Route path="/resume" component={Resume}/>
             
          </div>
        </div>
        </HashRouter>
    );
  }
}
 
export default Main;
```

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Main from "./Main";
 
ReactDOM.render(
  <Main/>, 
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
 
class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>HELLO</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
 
export default Home;
```

Comment: Try to wrap your `Route` into `Switch` imported from `react-router-dom`. [Ref](https://blog.pusher.com/getting-started-with-react-router-v4/). Can you also post `About` and `Resume` components?

Comment: can you also show the following components `About` and `Resume`

Answer (score 0):

Hi it is working fine here. Please check this example:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, HashRouter, Link, NavLink, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <HashRouter>
                <div>
                    <h1>Simple SPA</h1>
                    <ul className="header">
                        <li><NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
                        <li><NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink></li>
                        <li><NavLink to="/resume">Resume</NavLink></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div className="content">
                        <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
                        <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
                        <Route path="/resume" component={Resume}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </HashRouter>
        )
    }
}
export default App;

class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>HELLO</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class About extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>About</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Resume extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Resume</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```